# How can I get the last-modified time with python3 urllib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

I'm porting over a [program of mine](http://github.com/Daenyth/pkgtools/blob/2to3/scripts/pkgfile.py#L190) from python2 to python3, and I'm hitting the following error: `AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getdate'`

Here's the code:

```
conn = urllib.request.urlopen(fileslist, timeout=30)
last_modified = conn.info().getdate('last-modified')
```

This section worked under python 2.7, and so far I haven't been able to find out the correct method to get this information in python 3.1.

The full context is an update method. It pulls new files from a server down to its local database, but only if the file on the server is newer than the local file. If there's a smarter way to achieve this functionality than just comparing local and remote file timestamps, then I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`conn.headers['last-modified']` works under both Python 2 and Python 3. Comparing filestamps seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Also, the header returns a string, but the old method returned a `struct_time` (or similar). This should work to massage it: `time_struct = time.strptime(last_modified, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')`