# Getting last modified date of file on FTP server using urlopen not working

Tags: python, ftp, urllib, six

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, urlrequest

conn = urlopen('ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/lftx.sfc.2017.nc', timeout=20)
last_modified = conn.headers['last-modified']
```

Following [How can I get the last-modified time with python3 urllib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022083/how-can-i-get-the-last-modified-time-with-python3-urllib) I want to get last modification date of a file on a FTP server. However, with the code above, `last-modified` is `None`. Any suggestions? I want solution to work on both python 2 and python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of `urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) does not claim that it returns `last-modified` for FTP URLs.

Note that there are no headers in FTP protocol. The `urlopen` just fakes few HTTP-like headers for some kind of compatibility of the interface across protocols.

To retrieve timestamp using FTP, use the ftplib. See [How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848).